# How to use sapply to access alternate rows and form matrix from it

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following data:

```
Method1 100x   0.9736842   0.9736842   0.9473684   0.9473684
Method2  100x  0   0.5 0.917   0.667
Method1 50x     0.5 0.4210526   0.3421053   0.6315789
Method2  50x   0   0.417   0.750   0.883
```

What I want to do is to use `sapply` function to extract rows from the same coverage (100x, 50x)
grouping and then form the matrix

Resulting

```
#100x
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] 0.9736842 0.9736842 0.9473684 0.9473684
[2,] 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.9170000 0.6670000

#50x
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] 0.5000000 0.4210526 0.3421053 0.6315789
[2,] 0.0000000 0.4170000 0.7500000 0.8830000
```

What I have is the following code but didn't produce result 
as I want:

```
 dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1586262/plain/")
 colnames(dat) <- c("Method", "Coverage",  "error 0%", "error 1%", "error 2%", "error 4%")

  sapply(3:6,
   function(x) {
      tmp <- matrix(dat[,x],nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
      print(tmp);
   }
  )
```

What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
> dat<-read.table(text="Method1 100x   0.9736842   0.9736842   0.9473684   0.9473684
+ Method2  100x  0   0.5 0.917   0.667
+ Method1 50x     0.5 0.4210526   0.3421053   0.6315789
+ Method2  50x   0   0.417   0.750   0.883")
> colnames(dat) <- c("Method", "Coverage",  "error 0%", "error 1%", "error 2%", "error 4%")
> lapply(unique(dat$Coverage),function(x)dat[dat$Coverage==x,])
[[1]]
   Method Coverage  error 0%  error 1%  error 2%  error 4%
1 Method1     100x 0.9736842 0.9736842 0.9473684 0.9473684
2 Method2     100x 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.9170000 0.6670000

[[2]]
   Method Coverage error 0%  error 1%  error 2%  error 4%
3 Method1      50x      0.5 0.4210526 0.3421053 0.6315789
4 Method2      50x      0.0 0.4170000 0.7500000 0.8830000
```

Edit: To get matrices without the first two columns and no attributes:

```
> lapply(unique(dat$Coverage),function(x){
  z<-as.matrix(dat[dat$Coverage==x,-(1:2)])
  colnames(z)=NULL
  rownames(z)=NULL
  z})
[[1]]
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.9736842 0.9736842 0.9473684 0.9473684
[2,] 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.9170000 0.6670000

[[2]]
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  0.5 0.4210526 0.3421053 0.6315789
[2,]  0.0 0.4170000 0.7500000 0.8830000
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get rid of colnames and first two columns?
I want to get the raw value in the matrix without any attributes.

Comment: Try `lapply(unique(dat$Coverage),function(x)as.matrix(dat[dat$Coverage==x,-(1:2)]))`

Answer (score 4):

This logically seems like a good case for `split`:

```
lapply(split(dat[3:6], dat$Coverage),function(x) unname(as.matrix(x)) )

#$`100x`
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] 0.9736842 0.9736842 0.9473684 0.9473684
#[2,] 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.9170000 0.6670000
#
#$`50x`
#     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#[1,]  0.5 0.4210526 0.3421053 0.6315789
#[2,]  0.0 0.4170000 0.7500000 0.8830000
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you just want to extract the rows for each coverage? e.g.

```
# extract the '100x' rows, columns 3 to 6
subset(dat, Coverage=='100x', 3:6)
#   error 0%  error 1%  error 2%  error 4%
#1 0.9736842 0.9736842 0.9473684 0.9473684
#2 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.9170000 0.6670000
```

You can convert to a matrix with `as.matrix` (it will retain the column names, but you can strip them with you want with `unname`). The workhorse here is the `subset` function (you can also do this with `dat[dat$Coverage=='100x', 3:6]`; there are many other ways to extract that subset).

If you wanted to do this for each Coverage level, you could do a loop

```
for (c in levels(dat$Coverage)) { #loops through values of Coverage
    ss <- subset(dat, Coverage==c, 3:6)
    # do something with ss
}
```

For example, if you wanted a *list* with an element per Coverage level, you could use `lapply` (which has the for loop built in)

```
lapply(levels(dat$Coverage), function (c) subset(dat, Coverage==c, 3:6))
# [[1]]
#    error 0%  error 1%  error 2%  error 4%
# 1 0.9736842 0.9736842 0.9473684 0.9473684
# 2 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.9170000 0.6670000
# 
# [[2]]
#   error 0%  error 1%  error 2%  error 4%
# 3      0.5 0.4210526 0.3421053 0.6315789
# 4      0.0 0.4170000 0.7500000 0.8830000
```

In your  code you seem to be looping through the columns 3-6, whereas in your question it seems you want to loop through coverage levels instead.

Comment: Your second example is essentially `split(dat[3:6], dat$Coverage)` no?

Comment: Hah, I've been using R for ages and didn't know about the `split` function.